# UI for predicting game results

Tags: web-app, html, selection

I will ask users to predict the outcome of upcoming football games.

**Ideas on how to enter the data**

a) Two separate `textbox` inputs
b) Two separate `select` tags with options: 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 9, 10
c) One `select` tag with possible game outcomes: 0-0, 1-0, 2-0, 3-0 ... 0-1,0-2 ... 9-10, 10-10

[image: Select options]

**Conditions:**

- They will predict a lot of games (but will be able to save 5-10 results at a time)
- They are mainly using mobile phones

**Some cons:**

- Using `textbox` will render the keyboard on mobile phone every time they click a new field
- There will be a limitation with `select` as I have to define the max amount of goals/result possible
- Using `select` with possible game outcomes will render a list with a lot of (probably) unnecessary options. It will be harder to find the desired result

What is the preferred way for users to predict the outcome of football games?

Comment: secret option #4: use range inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would much prefer to enter scores using **Option A**.

You mention that rendering the keyboard every time will be cumbersome, but I'd either just tap between the two fields (which I imagine most users would do) or click the "tab" button above my keyboard to navigate focus between form elements. Both of these actions would keep the keyboard active (at least on my iPhone, this is how it works...).

I would avoid dropdowns on mobile like the plague. It has a decidedly negative effect on user experience. Most of the first page Google results for "[dropdown on mobile](https://www.google.com/search?q=dropdown+on+mobile)" also contain the word "alternatives" or "last resort". I'd *especially* not go with Option C, as that would provide the least concise interaction of the three options.

Comment: Interesting, I didn’t know about avoiding dropdowns on mobile. I read the first hit on your google search: https://medium.com/@kollinz/dropdown-alternatives-for-better-mobile-forms-53e40d641b53 Halfway down the article they offer a fourth solution, to use steppers. I think I go with textboxes anyway (because they are more well known), but are there any reasons to consider using steppers in my scenario?

Comment: Yeah, overall dropdowns just tend to be a really tedious interaction method for touch devices, and typically you can find another more friendly type of input that's just as suitable. Steppers would be okay if your user's input will be between 0 and 5 the vast majority of the time (good use case: # of guests in a hotel room). Even if you provide the ability to increment, decrement, or input your own value, a naive user will likely still click/tap the buttons each time, as that's what the obvious affordance is. If they're betting the game will be 7-8 (unusual for soccer), that's 15 clicks/taps.

Comment: (Meant to ping you in the last comment, but ran out of space, @Nurp)